# C++ Windows form Application : How to show back a previous form when I click a button at current form?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2012

For example I have 2 forms in my application, form1 and form2.

```
     this->Hide();
     Form2^ f2 = gcnew Form2();
     f2->ShowDialog();
```

I am using the code above to hide form1 and show form2, but how do I hide form2 and show back form1 when I click a button in form2?

Comment: put some codes. Then we can help you better.

Comment: I had editted some codes that I use to hide form1 and then form2 appears, but I get an error "undeclared identifier" when I do the same when I want to hide form2 and show back form1.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
this->Hide();
 Form2^ f2 = gcnew Form2();
 if(f2->DoModal()==IDOK)
   this->Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to hold a reference of `Form1` in `Form2`. Maybe you can send it via its constructor to `Form2`. Then on `Form2`'s button click you should invoke `show` or `showDialog` methods of the reference of the `Form1` and `hide` method of `this` as `Form1` this time.